# chart in Kibana that calculates the number of occurence of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I have a set of data which looks like this.
The number oposite a language is the proportion of this language used in the repository in percentage.

```
{
 "repository" : "https://github.com/xxx",
 "nb_users" : 150,
 "project" : "projectA",
 "languages" : {
            "COBOL" : 9.54,
            "Batchfile" : 0.0,
            "CSS" : 0.03,
            "HTML" : 37.4,
            "Java" : 53.02
          }
}
{
 "repository" : "https://github.com/yyy",
 "nb_users" : 120,
 "project" : "projectA",
 "languages" : {
            "Javascript" : 33.98,
            "Java" : 56.02
          }
}                 
{
 "repository" : "https://github.com/zzz",
 "nb_users" : 10,
 "project" : "projectB",
 "languages" : {
            "C#" : 90,
            "HTML": 5,
            "Java" : 5
          }
}
```

I would like to do 2 things with Kibana

1) have an overall assessment of the languages. 
I would like to have a pie chart, each slice representing a language, i.e. I want to count the number of occurence of the fields languages.Java, languages.C, etc
In this case, Java appears 3 times, HTML 2 times and the rest once.

=> How would I do to draw such a pie chart in Kibana ?

2) gather all the language information per project and per repository, without taking into account the percentage.
i.e. I would like to be able to identify that 
COBOL is used in 1 project and 1 repository
JAVA is used in 2 project and 3 repositories 
 => How would I do to display this information in say a histogram ?
 Example :  a histogram per language. The Y-axis would be the number of projects using a given language and the X-axis would be made of the different languages.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do partially what I wanted.
i.e. having the number of repositories using a specific language and putting that in a pie chart.

In a kibana, I created a pie chart in the vizualisation section :

In the Metrics section : make a aggregation with a "Unique count" of the field "repository"

In the Buckets section, use "Split slices" and use  "Filters" as Aggregation.
Add a filter per language.
So one filter would be : "language.COBOL:*" 
another filter would be : "language.Batchfile:*"

=> I end up with a pie chart, each slice containing the number of repositories for each language.